# Derivative of the exponential map

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I'm new to Riemannian geometry and always confused by the derivatives there. Consider on a Riemannian manifold $M$, define the following map

$$u(r,\theta)=\text{exp}_{x} (rf(\theta))$$
where $x \in M$, $r \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(\theta)\in T_xM$.

What is $\partial_{r}u$? I know it is equal to $f(\theta)$ when$ r=0$, what about other $r$? Also, how to compute $\partial_{\theta}u$ ?

Comment: I always give the same answer to all questions about the exponential map, especially those about the derivative of the exponential map. It's all best understood using Jacobi fields. A Jacobi field is an infinitesimal variation of a geodesic. Since the exponential map defines a family of (radial) geodesics, its differential is an infinitesimal variation of a geodesic and therefore corresponds to a Jacobi field. Jacobi fields are more concrete and easier to understand than the mysterious looking "$d\exp_x(rf(\theta))$". So look for them in your or some other textbook.

Answer (score 2):

If $x \in M$ is fixed, and you want to compute the partial derivative $(\partial_ru)(r,\theta)$, you compute the derivative of the map $$r \mapsto rf(\theta) \mapsto \exp_x(rf(\theta)),$$which is the composition $\exp_x \circ (r \mapsto f(\theta))$, where $\theta$ is fixed. Thus $$(\partial_ru)(r,\theta) = {\rm d}(\exp_x)_{rf(\theta)}(f(\theta)),$$where one thinks of $f(\theta)$ as an element of $T_{rf(\theta)}(T_xM) \cong T_xM$. At $r = 0$, of course this boils down to $(\partial_ru)(0,\theta) = f(\theta)$.

Similarly, for $(\partial_\theta u)(r,\theta)$, you compute the derivative of the map $$\theta \mapsto rf(\theta) \mapsto \exp_x(rf(\theta)),$$which is the composition $\exp_x \circ (\theta \mapsto rf(\theta))$, where $r$ is fixed, and this yields $(\partial_\theta u)(r,\theta) = {\rm d}(\exp_x)_{rf(\theta)}(rf'(\theta))$. This time you see that $(\partial_\theta u)(0,\theta) = 0$, which makes sense geometrically. So essentially, the question boils down to what you know about the derivative ${\rm d}(\exp_x)_v$ for $v \neq 0$. Even if you don't know much, you may be able to combine the above computations with results such as the Gauss lemma to achieve whatever is it that you're trying to do here.